# Django: ajax request url is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm working with  Django 1.3 and making a ajax request  to a view having following url pattern:

my current url from which request is made `/add/`

```
url(r'^university/teacher/signup/$', 'uninversity.views.signup', name='teacher-signup'),
```

making ajax request as

```
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url teacher-signup %}",
         });
```

which is coming as

```
/add/%7B%%20url%20'teacher-signup'%20%%7D
```

instead of

```
university/teacher/signup/
```

any clue on that ?

Answer (score 1):

You problem is the double quotes around  **"{% url teacher-signup %}"**
This is causing it to be ignored during render.  Do you have your script in your Django template?

You should actually be able to use single quotes around it and it should render like you would expect

```
url: '{% url teacher-signup %}',
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode the url so the spaces and parameters are represented correctly. Use [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI):

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: decodeURI('{% url teacher-signup %}'),
 });
```

Example:

```
decodeURI("https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript_%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B");
// "https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/JavaScript_шеллы"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an ajax call that I use, I always put the url like that, maybe this can help you.

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "/BusquedaCIE10",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    grupname: idgrupo,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
```

url.py

```
      url(r'^BusquedaCIE10','expmedico.views.ciesearch'),
```

views.py

```
def ciesearch(request):
    if request.POST.has_key('idgrupo') and request.is_ajax():
        x = request.POST['idgrupo']
        y = cie_10.objects.filter(id=x)
        miembroinf = serializers.serialize('json', y)
        return HttpResponse(miembroinf, mimetype="application/json")
    else:
        return render_to_response('csb.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```